# Internal mechanisms of mounting an ext2 file system image and managing changes

Tags: filesystems, kernel, linux-kernel, mount, fsck

For a OS project, I am creating a ext2 file system image and mounting it. This means that I am writing out a 1 MB file with block information and then using it as the mount target.

For example, assume there is a file called `base.img`:

```
fsck.ext2 base.img # checking my file system 
mkdir mnt
sudo mount -o loop base.img mnt
```

After the mount is successful, what is happening internally? From my understanding, my `base.img` simply initializes the image correctly. Internally, these are my questions:

- Is there now a drive partition with this file system?
- How are changes to the file system managed?

For the second, from my understanding, there exists a "mount table" and perhaps an `ext2` module that Linux will use for further changes. Will these changes be reflected in `base.img` or is there a new disk partition for it now?

My underlying question here is: how does this all work, especially with varying implementations and ambiguity?

Comment: Nit picks.  You can't use a file as a mount target: base.img is the *source*, and the target must be a directory.  base.img doesn't "intialize" an image, it IS the image.  There is no partition because you didn't use fdisk on base.img, it's a whole disk image with no partition.   When you mount it with -o loop, an existing loop device is associated with it, so there is not a new drive.

Comment: To clarify, base.img is the image and it is used as the “disk partition”, facilitated by the loop device?

Comment: It's not a partition.  It is a disk image.  You partition a disk into multiple pieces, and those pieces are found by looking at the partition table.  base.img is not a partition, it is a whole disk image without a partition table.  You can do this with real disks too -- partitions are frequently used but are not always required.  It is very common for small USB sticks to not have a partition table.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. You're saying that the disk is partitioned, and this is just an "image" that is already structured. In things like small USB sticks, you may just have a monolithic "image" and not have partitions that you use for individual, smaller images.

Comment: Image implies that it might be a copy of something that is or will be on a disk.  The image is "structured" in that it contains a filesystem, which is created by mkfs, repaired by fsck, mounted by mount.  Typically, the filesystem occupies every block in the image or disk or partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mount -o loop base.img mnt
```

uses [a loop device](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html) to make `base.img` available as a block device, and mounts that block device under `mnt`. There is no new partition on disk; all changes to `mnt` are stored in `base.img`.

If `base.img` contains an ext2 file system, its contents will indeed be managed by [the kernel’s ext2 driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext2).